# Path.GetFullPath — Return only the last folder, file name and extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to get the path for files within the web app, but it returns the path within my computer.

I am using mvc 5 and ef 6, basically users can upload pictures, all uploaded pictures goes into ~/Upload_Files/"username of current user"/

The upload method will get the username of the current user and if if that folder exist, if not it creates one and upload all pics into that folder.

The main action method is to display all pictures within /Upload_Files folder included the ones inside sub folders.

This is within that action method:

```
var imagesModel = new ImageGallery();
var imageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(
    Server.MapPath("~/Upload_Files/"), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var item in imageFiles)
{
    // imagesModel.ImageList.Add(Path.GetFileName(item));
    imagesModel.ImageList.Add(Path.GetFullPath(item));
}
return View(imagesModel);`
```

Inside cshtml to display the pictures

```
<img src="@Url.Content(image)" width="150" height="150"/>
```

If I use GetFullPath, it will return the location within my computer so pictures wont show.

I tried it with GetFileName and create the rest of the string as ("~/Upload_Files" + item) which would work if the pictures are stored only within Upload_Files folder and not in sub folders. Also tried user ("~/Upload_Files/" + User.Identity etc + "/" + item) and so on. Anyone could give me an idea on this please? Just started mvc recently.

Also my main goals are to display all images within sub folders, if user click on picture it will pull up all pictures only for that user (which is just to reference his/her username somehow) and lastly to allow users to delete their own pictures. Any more convenient way of doing it?

Any help much appreciated!

**New Method**

Upload Image Method

```
if (Request.Files.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
                int fileSize = file.ContentLength;
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string user = User.Identity.GetUserName();
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Upload_Files/" + user + "/");
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Upload_Files/" + user + "/" + fileName));
                ImageGallery imageGallery = new ImageGallery();
                imageGallery.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
                imageGallery.Name = fileName;
                imageGallery.ImagePath = "~/Upload_Files/" + user + fileName;
                imageGallery.UserId = user;
                db.ImageGallery.Add(imageGallery);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return Content("Success");
        }
        return Content("failed");
```

Index action method

```
public ActionResult Indexnew()
    {
        var imagesModel = new ImageGallery
        {
            ImagePath = Datalayer.GetImagePaths()
        };
        return View("Indexnew", imagesModel);
    }
```

ImageGallery class

```
public class ImageGallery
{
    public ImageGallery()
    {
        ImageList = new List<string>();
    }
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> ImagePath { get; set; }
    public List<string> ImageList { get; set; }

}
```

Indexnew View

```
@model MM5.Models.ImageGallery
@foreach (var image in Model)
            {
                <p>@image</p>
                <a id="ShowImage" title="Photo" href="@Url.Action("Details","ImageGallery", User.Identity.Name)">

                    @*<img src="@Url.Content("~/Upload_Files/" + image. + "/" + image)" width="150" height="150" />*@
                    <img src="@Url.Content(image)" width="150" height="150" />

                </a>
            }
```

I think my view is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not calling methods from inside your view. You can get path mapping however by using

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/Upload_Files");
```

You should pass a ViewModel to your view with all of the paths of your images

You should have a relative mapping, or have setup a virtual directory hosted on IIS, and then take the relative paths and append them. You should store your image directory in your

`Web.config`

```
<add key="ImageUrl" value="/Upload_Files/" />
```

`Controller`

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var homeVm = new HomeVM
        {
            ImagePaths = DataLayer.GetImagePaths()
        };
        return View("Index", homeVm);
    }
```

`ViewModel`

```
    class HomeVM
    {
            public IEnumerable<string> ImagePaths { get; set; }
    }
```

`DataLayer`

I would suggest not enumerating the files each time as this will severely hinder performance of your application. You should store the urls of the images in a database and perform something like

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetImagePaths()
    {
        var imageUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageUrl"];
        var db = new MyDataClassDataContext();
        var value = (from im in db.Images select imageUrl + im.Path).ToList();
        db.Dispose();
        return value;
    }
```

So, whenever an image is uploaded or changed, you should modify the value in your table. This will greatly increase performance of your application

Comment: How can I store the image directory in the `web.config` ? I tried to find some useful info about but no luck yet. To be honest, I have only started learning MVC and still not clear on a lot of things, but surely I would like to use the best method to improve performance.

Comment: I have added image path to the database and I can store there the right string for the virtual path if Im correct:) I have saved the GetImagePath method in a new class called datalayer and changed the controller. It comes back with an error, no null and i think it does count the number of files within all sub folders, but image id and other attributes come back as null...

Comment: @Sugafree Sorry, I didn't mean to give the impression that you actually store the images in the `web.config`. You should add an key entry for the path where the images are stored. ie `<add key="MyImageUrl" value="/Upload_Files/" />` This will allow you to change your path if you move from staging to production, or if you have to perform a migration of data, without having to recompile. When you read from your database, the relative paths, you can append them in your DataLayer select statement

Comment: @Sugafree See modified answer to include `web.config` and altered select from db in DataLayer

Comment: `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MM5.Models.ImageGallery'.`  This is the error I am getting.

Comment: Seems like the view is not right, I was playing around with it for a while but either got an error or did not pass anything to the view. Also now I ran into another problem as I have changed Path to IEnumerable string in the model and in the upload image method I get an error saying you can not convert type string to IEnumerable. Again I have changed it in the model class. I will upload these new bits in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to map images which are in target directory or it's sub-directories, then I would suggest this:

```
public string ReverseMapPath(string path)
{
    string appPath = Server.MapPath("~");
    return string.Format("~{0}", path.Replace(appPath, "").Replace("\\", "/"));
}

...

imagesModel.ImageList.Add(ReverseMapPath(item));
```

Basically, the `ReverseMapPath` function translates given file system path into application virtual path.
For example:

`D:\Web\MyApp\Upload_Files\User123\Holiday\Italy.jpg`

is translated into

`~/Upload_Files/User123/Holiday/Italy.jpg`

Just wondering why such function does not already exist inside framework.

Comment: I think it isn't included because it is not good practice to get your paths that way from a web application

Comment: And what is the proper way?
The ASP.Net allows converting virtual path into physical path, I don't see much of a reason not to implement vice versa.

Comment: I can see the use to get a single folder's mapped path, but not to enumerate that folder. I'm sure there are scenarios I'm not thinking of, but it is bad practice to enumerate images, unless the images will be completely unknown on application startup, in the instance of some game or similar. If these will be user uploaded images, then the paths should be stored and managed.